# Why does my Swift DataTask completion handler never run?

Tags: swift, http, request, urlsession

I am trying to write a Swift Requests struct that contains methods like get, post, put, delete, etc. to make API requests in a simplified manner.

Here is my **requests.swift** file:

```
import Foundation


struct Requests {
    
    static func makeGet(url: URL, after: @escaping (Data?, Error?) -> Void) {
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            print("Inside task")
            after(data, error)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    
}
```

Here is my **main.swift** file where I call the makeGet function:

```
import Foundation

let url = URL(string: "https://api.edamam.com/api/food-database/v2/parser?app_id=4c38caa6&app_key=kkk&ingr=eggs 4 small".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!)!

Requests.makeGet(url: url) { d, e in
    print("Inside closure from main")
    print(d)
    print(e)
}
```

**The data-task does not run and I know that because I see nothing (apart from *Finished with exit code 0*) output.**

Comment: Could not replicate your issue, all works well for me in my basic tests.
 On MacOS 14.3, using Xcode 15.2 and SwiftUI. I get
 `{"status":"error","message":"Unauthorized app_id = 4c38caa6"}`

Comment: Thanks, I made this on a MacOS command line app. It is very strange and I've never had it before!

Comment: Works well on MacOS (SwiftUI) as well. Try
in the Signing & capabilities -> App Sandbox -> Outgoing Connections (Client)

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for this tip! For future readers **I managed to get it working with the tips [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/713085)**